# VBA PivotTable error when updating table in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm having one issue to perform a loop for 1 pivot table on excel file:
I just want to change the `model2` from `IJ`to `CV`

```
For i = 7 To 11

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela  
    dinâmica1").PivotFields("MODEL2").CurrentPage _
         = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotFields("MODEL2")
        .PivotItems("CV").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("IJ").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    cel4 = "AV" & i
    cel3 = "AX" & i
    Worksheets("DDTZ C").Range("AZ" & i).Formula = "=Iferror(IF(" & cel4 &   
    "="""","""",VLookup(" & cel3 & ", AT:AV, 3, False)),"""")"

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela 
    dinâmica1").PivotFields("MODEL2").CurrentPage _
         = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotFields("MODEL2")
         .PivotItems("CV").Visible = True
         .PivotItems("IJ").Visible = False
         .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With

    Worksheets("DDTZ C").Range("BA" & i).Value = "=Iferror(IF(" & cel4 & 
    "="""","""",VLookup(" & cel3 & ", AT:AV, 3, False)),"""")"

Next i
```

This loop has worked perfectly on first loop, however, when it start the second loop `i = 8`, an error appears to me, I have checked the script, and the problem is related to the followed part:

```
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela  
         dinâmica1").PivotFields("MODEL2").CurrentPage _
         = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotFields("MODEL2")
        .PivotItems("CV").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("IJ").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
```

I cannot understand why I'm having a problem with that, since it works fine on the first loop `i = 7`

Anyone can help with that issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @YowE3K are you taking this ? Can i quit for bed ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Nah - I just edited out the [macros] tag - pivot tables aren't my thing, so I would rather you answer - drink some more coffee - stay awake a bit longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below.

**Note**: I've debugged only the `PivotTable` section, not the formula.

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

' set the Pivot Table into a variable
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 7 To 11
    With PvtTbl
        With .PivotFields("MODEL2")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .PivotItems("CV").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With

        cel4 = "AV" & i
        cel3 = "AX" & i

        ' === Not debugging your formula part ===
        Worksheets("DDTZ C").Range("AZ" & i).Formula = "=Iferror(IF(" & cel4 &
        "="""","""",VLookup(" & cel3 & ", AT:AV, 3, False)),"""")"

        With .PivotFields("MODEL2")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .PivotItems("IJ").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With

        ' === Not debugging your formula part ===
        Worksheets("DDTZ C").Range("BA" & i).Value = "=Iferror(IF(" & cel4 &
        "="""","""",VLookup(" & cel3 & ", AT:AV, 3, False)),"""")"
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Shai Rado, it has worked perfectly